# Why doesn't this array of structure assignment compile?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
here is the code 

struct point_tag {
        int x;
        int y;
};

typedef struct point_tag Point;

int main(void) 
{
      Point pt[] = { {10,20}, {30, 40}, {50,60}};
      pt[0] = {100,200};
}
```

When i do `pt[0] = {100, 200}`, the compiler keeps complaining of

> error:expected expression before '{' token

I don't really get that though. Isn't the expression before the { token assignment operator(=)?

I don't understand why the assignment would be an issue though. the value at address pt refers to an array of Point. I am just setting the 0th Point to be this new point and i know that assigning a struct in a format like `{100,200}` is legal where the elements inside that array are just fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For assignment, typecast the value to type Point to make it a [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html):

```
pt[0] = (Point){100,200};
```

[Live code](http://ideone.com/21hKo2) using gcc

This is equivalent to

```
{
  Point temp = {100,200};
  pt[0] = temp;
}
```

<sup>p.s. Compound literal is not available in old strict C89 compliant compiler. It is avilable in GCC for C89 as extension and in C99 compound literal is a core feature.</sup>

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have to do this for {10,20}, {30,40}, and {50,60} ? That trips me up. Technically you're still assigning those values to the value at those indexes in the array

Comment: Because the above construct is available only for initialization. In `pt[0] = (Point){100,200};`, you are creating a temp `Point` and assigning it to `pt[0]`. You must tell compiler whether `{100, 200}` is a `Point` or `int [2]` or something else.

Comment: but couldn't this be similar logic in that you're also creating a temp Point {10,20} and storing that as the value of the first index in the array?

Comment: If my previous comment fails to answer your query, I would suggest you a read through C99 specs section 6.5.2.5 Compound literals.

Comment: @committedandroider You can also do something like [pt[0] = (Point){.x = 100, .y = 200};](http://ideone.com/Bkv5nu). Without telling the type, compiler would have no idea what x and y are.